# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Facing some strange with **ui-router** angularjs. I am configuring an single page application using these frameworks.
Here is my code

```
function initWmappConfig($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $compileProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider.
        state('login', { url: '/', templateUrl: '/Views/login', controller: 'login-controller', controllerAs: 'vm' })
        .state('register', { url: '/register', templateUrl: '/Views/Register', controller: 'login-controller', controllerAs: 'vm' });

    $stateProvider.state('otherwise', {url: '/'});

    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}
```

If i am using this above configuration i am facing this war

> **WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once**

but on other hand if i simple change

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

then everything seems to work just fine...

Please let me know why this is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because you didn't mention the `.html` extension in the templateUrl

```
  state('login', { url: '/', templateUrl: '/Views/login.html', controller: 'login-controller', controllerAs: 'vm' })
  .state('register', { url: '/register', templateUrl: '/Views/Register.html', controller: 'login-controller', controllerAs: 'vm' });
```

Also for `otherwise`, you need to use `$urlRouterProvider`

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Comment: i am handling the extension on server side...i mean on route change one server side event will fire and checking the route and adding .cshtml extension to it..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error.
The reason behind this is the use of jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/public/vendor/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/public/vendor/angular/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I removed the following and warning disappeared:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```